# Synthesizing Audio no response given

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, text-to-speech, google-cloud-speech, google-text-to-speech

Below is the relevant code :

```
try (TextToSpeechClient textToSpeechClient = TextToSpeechClient.create(settings))
        {
            System.out.println("In Try - Create TTS client");
            logger.info("In Try - Create TTS client");
            // Set the text input to be synthesized
            SynthesisInput input = SynthesisInput.newBuilder().setText(receivedtext).build();

            // Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
            VoiceSelectionParams voice = VoiceSelectionParams.newBuilder().setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .setSsmlGender(SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE).build();
            logger.info("Set Voice Params");

            // Select the type of audio file you want returned
            AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.newBuilder().setAudioEncoding(AudioEncoding.MP3).build();
            logger.info("Audio Configured");
            
            // Perform the text-to-speech request
            SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice, audioConfig);
            logger.info("Audio Synthesised");
            
            // Get the audio contents from the response
            ByteString audioContents = response.getAudioContent();

            // Write the response to the output file
            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(audioFileDirectory + audioFileName + audioFileFormat))
            {
                out.write(audioContents.toByteArray());
                logger.info("File Opened and Written");
            }
}
```

The line :  SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = textToSpeechClient.synthesizeSpeech(input, voice, audioConfig);

Is where, I think, our program connects to the server and synthesizes the audio and then it is supposed to output an mp3 file. The problem is the application just stops or waits at this and does not proceed.
Yesterday I had gotten a gRPC deadline exception. Tried to solve it but every solutions doesn't fit with the current versions.

Now this is another version of the program which is not returning any response.

Any solutions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance